# How to get a Matte/Clay render

Tags: rendering, texturing, blender-internal-render-engine, node-editor

Hello Blender Community,

I have a question for all you expert blender renderers.
I'm trying to achieve this super simple clay look. Is there anyone who could point me in the right direction to achieve something like this?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A simple shader node should work in Cycles render. It's using the new Principled BSDF shader with the roughness set to 1. Alternatively you could use a Diffuse BSDF shader with the roughness set to 1 and get the same result.

[image]

I have a main sun light source  with Ambient Occlusion under World->Ambient Occlusion and set the value to .1. If you increase the value for the Ambient Occlusion, you'll see less shadows.

[image]